# Why is the while loop stop working?

Tags: java, javafx, while-loop

I have 2 nested while loops, if i stop the inner loop, the outer stops checking if the inner runs. I have methods to start and stop the timer, but if i stop the timer and then restart it (set the boolean value to true) the timer dont start. If i execute some operations in the outer loop like System.out.println("test") while the inner is paused, it works fine.

```
@Override
protected synchronized Void call() throws Exception {
    while(true){
        System.out.println();
        while(play){
            System.out.println(play);
            secondCounter++;
            seconds++;
            if(seconds>59){
                secondCounter=0;
                seconds=0;
                minutes++;
            }
            if(minutes>59){
                minutes=0;
                hours++;
            }
            System.out.println("Task sekunden: "+seconds);
            setTime();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the complete class:

```
public class TimerTask extends Task<Void>{

private Label timer;
private boolean play=false;

private int secondCounter;

private int seconds;
private int minutes;
private int hours;

public TimerTask(Label timer){
    this.timer=timer;
}

@Override
protected synchronized Void call() throws Exception {
    while(true){
        while(play){
            System.out.println(play);
            secondCounter++;
            seconds++;
            if(seconds>59){
                secondCounter=0;
                seconds=0;
                minutes++;
            }
            if(minutes>59){
                minutes=0;
                hours++;
            }
            System.out.println("Task sekunden: "+seconds);
            setTime();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}

public int getMinutes(){
    int time;
    time=minutes + (hours*60);
    if(seconds>30){
        time++;
    }
    return time;
}

public void test(){
    String secondsTime;
    String minutesTime;
    String hoursTime;

    if(seconds<10){
        secondsTime="0"+seconds;
    }else{
        secondsTime=String.valueOf(seconds);
    }
    if(minutes<10){
        minutesTime="0"+minutes;
    }else{
       minutesTime=String.valueOf(minutes);
    }
    if(hours<10){
        hoursTime="0"+hours;
    }else{
        hoursTime=String.valueOf(hours);
    }

    System.out.println(hoursTime+":"+minutesTime+":"+secondsTime);
}

public void setTime(){
    String secondsTime;
    String minutesTime;
    String hoursTime;

    if(seconds<10){
        secondsTime="0"+seconds;
    }else{
        secondsTime=String.valueOf(seconds);
    }
    if(minutes<10){
        minutesTime="0"+minutes;
    }else{
       minutesTime=String.valueOf(minutes);
    }
    if(hours<10){
        hoursTime="0"+hours;
    }else{
        hoursTime=String.valueOf(hours);
    }
    Platform.runLater(() -> {timer.setText(hoursTime+":"+minutesTime+":"+secondsTime);});
}

public void stop(){
    this.play=false;
    System.out.println("Stop: "+play);
}

public void start(){
    this.play=true;
    System.out.println("Start: "+play);
}

public void reset(){
    this.play=false;
    secondCounter=0;
    seconds=0;
    minutes=0;
    hours=0;
    timer.setText("00:00:00");
    System.out.println("Reset: "+play);
}
```

}

Comment: What is `play` and how are you setting it?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Show the code, show the output you get and the output you're expecting. What is `play`? How is it defined? Do you really want to have a busy loop constantly writing new lines to the output when play is false?

Comment: play is a boolean value and i set it with some public setter and getter methods

Comment: That code is critical. Post it. If it's not volatile, then your code isn't thread-safe.

Comment: i posted the complete class

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ Asking to debug your simple program is a low quality question.

Comment: This is just a small part of a big one. I tried different things befor i ask here. But you are right, i will read this article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`play` is read and modified from several threads, but is not volatile. So you have no guarantee about its visibility. One thread could set it to true and another thread see it as false forever.

The rest of the code is also not thread-safe at all. All the shared state is accessed without any kind of synchronization.

So you really can't rely on anything in that code.

Comment: I just set the boolean value play to volatile and it works ... Thank you. I tried it with synchronized, but this let hang the whole GUI. Can you explain me why?

Comment: This topic would take a book to explain. Buy you a copy of "Java Concurrency in Practice", and read it. It's a must read if you want to be serious about multi-threading in Java.